# .getElementById IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dhtml, getelementbyid

I've got a JavaScript running 2 `".getElementById('').style"` changes. Both work perfectly in FF, but the first one doesn't work in IE7.

Appreciate all help :)

First SourceCode:

```
function ingen() {
    document.getElementById('merInfo1').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('merInfo2').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('merInfo3').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('merInfo4').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('merInfo5').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('merInfo6').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('merInfo7').style.display='none';
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="enkeltSkjema" id="avtaleInput">
    <select name="radio1" id="radio1">
        <option value="1" onClick="ingen()">lorem</option>
        <option value="2" onClick="some()">lorem</option>                                  
        <option value="3" onClick="other()">lorem</option>
        <option value="4" onClick="func()">lorem</option>
        <option value="5" onClick="tion()">lorem</option>
        <option value="6" onClick="names()">lorem</option>
        <option value="7" onClick="goes()">lorem</option>
        <option value="8" onClick="here()">lorem</option>
    </select>
</span>                          
<span class="enkeltSkjema" id="merInfo">
    <span id="merInfo1" name="merInfo1"></span>
    <span id="merInfo2" name="merInfo2"></span>
    <span id="merInfo3" name="merInfo3"></span>
    <span id="merInfo4" name="merInfo4"></span>
    <span id="merInfo5" name="merInfo5"></span>
    <span id="merInfo6" name="merInfo6"></span>
    <span id="merInfo7" name="merInfo7"></span>
</span>
```

Second, works fine in IE:

```
function levAdresse() {
    if (document.getElementById('egenLevAdr').checked == true) {
        document.getElementById('levAdrBox').style.display='block';
    }   
    else {
        document.getElementById('levAdrBox').style.display='none';
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="levAdrBox">
    <div id="levAdr">Field
        <span class="" id="levAdrInput"><input type="text" id="text12" name="text12" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="" id="levPostSted"> field:*
        <span class="" id="levPostStedInput">
            <input type="text" id="text18" name="text18" />
            <span class="" id="levPostNr">field:*
                <span class="" id="levPostNrInput">
                    <input type="text" id="text17" name="text17" />
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Uhhmmm... Maybe if you use "OnChange()" on the SELECT and not "OnClick" on OPTION ?

```
<select name="radio1" id="radio1" onChange="ingen(this.value)">
        <option value="1">lorem</option>
        <option value="2">lorem</option>                                  
        <option value="3">lorem</option>
        <option value="4">lorem</option>
        <option value="5">lorem</option>
        <option value="6">lorem</option>
        <option value="7">lorem</option>
        <option value="8">lorem</option>
</select>
```

and in the ingen(something) do a condition, or call other function in relation with the value passed... ?

Comment: Correct, onclick is not crossbrowsercompatible on options. http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/event_onclick.asp

Comment: doh, can't believe I missed that in the code sample! yes, the onclick on an option in IE will fail. (as will almost any event on an option in IE)

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you are calling the ingen() function before the DOM is fully constructed?

Comment: I don't think so since it's triggered by userinput. Anyway to check this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have ANY other elements ANYWHERE else on the page with a "name" attribute set to:

```
merInfo1
merInfo2
merInfo3
merInfo4
merInfo5
merInfo6
merInfo7
```

(of any case too: e.g. MerInfo1, merinfo1, MERinfo1 are all the same in IE)

if so, that's the bug. IE considers name to be the same as ID (which is a bug obviously)

Comment: Yeah, read about that. IE's got some hickups. Have cheched the script, and no. Added a name attribute with the same name, just in case ;) Didn't affect FF in any way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option/possibility, I'd use jQuery and get rid of (most of) the cross-browser incompatibilities:

```
function ingen() {
  $("#merInfo span").css("display", "none");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#egenLevAdr").click(function() { $("#levAdrBox").toggle(); });
});
```

Comment: Thanx for the tip! Does Jquery need som sort of script call?

Comment: Thanx again. Going to check out this alternative.

Comment: Checked it out now, but sadly IE is illiterate. Worked fine in FF, as always. Thanx again, nice code.